# Is there any possible bound on the derivative of a mapping $v(t) : (0 ,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert v(t) \rVert=1$?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The question is as in the title.

Let $v(t) : (0 ,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable maaping such that $\lVert v(t) \rVert=1$? holds for all $t$.

Then is it possible to give a bound on the norm of $v'(t)$? At least is there any way to characterize $v(t)$?

Could anyone please help me? What if I restrict the domain to a bounded region?

Comment: No. $v$ is a trajectory on the unit sphere and $v'$ is its velocity.

Comment: Bounds on the function rarely gives you bounds on the derivatives (holomorphic or harmonic functions, using Cauchy’s inequalities/mean-value property are the few exceptions). On the other hand, bounds on the derivative plus a little extra usually give you bounds on the original function (eg local Lipschitz bounds using mean-value inequality, or in more fancy applications, Sobolev’s inequalities). A concrete counterexample here is very easy as well: imagine going faster and faster around in a circle (as said above).

Comment: Take $n=2$ and $t\mapsto(\cos(e^t),\sin(e^t))$ to get 'faster and faster around in a circle' as peek-a-boo says

Answer (score 3):

Provided that $n>1$, the answer is **no.**

The fact that $v$ has norm $1$ just restricts the trajectory to the unit sphere $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. There is no restriction on its derivative.

For example $n=2$, consider
$$
v(t) = \bigl( \cos \omega(t), \sin \omega(t) \bigr) 
$$
for an arbitrary function $\omega: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $\| v(t) \| = 1$ for all $t \in (0, \infty)$, but $\| v'(t) \| = |\omega'(t)|$, which we have no control over.

For an explicit example with derivative of unbounded magnitude, consider $\omega(t) = t^2$, so $\| v'(t) \| = 2t$, which is unbounded.

These examples work in any dimension via the natural embedding into, say, the first two coordinates: $\mathbb{R}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.